# Sharing static IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-router, ip-address, static-ip

I want to share the one static IP address my office has (small office).  My boss has the DSL coming into an IP telephony box/router, with one Ethernet port coming out. `ipconfig` shows the gateway to be 72.24*x*.*xx*.*xxx*, and the one PC that is hooked up is one digit higher: 72.24*x*.*xx*.*xx*(*x*+1).

So thought I could hook up a Westell router off the telephony box’s Ethernet port, set the Westell router’s public LAN to the PC’s static IP address, and then assign DHCP to the PC.

It isn't working - my questions are:

1. Will the router translate the IP addresses through an Ethernet port instead of the DSL uplink? (There is no Ethernet uplink port *per se*.)
2. Do I have to set a default gateway on the PCs?
3. The router wants IP provider info.  What should I tell it?

Comment: It could be PPOE coming in, do you'd be required to enter auth info... Otherwise, some ISPs like to associate the first MAC address seen as the trusted source. There could be a need to clone the Mac of the desktop on the router. But that is a limited number of ISPs, and few routers support Mac clones. (Although, ddwrt firmware supports it).

Comment: i tried to connect to the telephony router with a browser, but no luck.  they must have it locked.  thx

Comment: but i still am not sure- will the westell router do the IP translation even though it not uplinking through the dsl port, but an ehternet port instead